# 0403-053 Expression is not complete; more tokens expected

Tags: ksh, aix

I have this piece of code given below as a part of my main script

```
if [ -e /tmp/rsm/Logs/filename_$$.txt ];
then
{
total=0
for files in $(<filename_$$.txt);
do
#cd /tmp/rsm/Logs
docs=`grep -i "Number.*processed" $files | cut -d" " -f5`
total=$(($total+$docs))
done
echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
echo  "Total Number Of Documents Processed On $date : $total"
echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
}
else
{
echo "There are "0" logfiles processed on $date"
}
fi
```

which gives the error

```
SDSLoad_onscreendocs.ksh[32]: 1024+: 0403-053 Expression is not complete; more tokens expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

that because of following lines

```
docs=`grep -i "Number.*processed" $files | cut -d" " -f5`
total=$(($total+$docs))
```

if `docs` variable is null then you will face this issue or might be `docs` having different value other than integer. so you need to check that manually or in debug mode.

also you can add one more checking, let say if docs if null then set zero 
eg.

```
[ -z $docs ] && docs=0
```

Or more clear is short circuit :

```
docs=$(grep -i "Number.*processed" $files | cut -d" " -f5 || echo 0)
```